# selinux in a chroot environment

Tags: linux, ssh, selinux

I need to change selinux policy for /etc/ssh/sshd_config in a chroot environment designed to rescue my system (on a dedibox) : it actually does not have any selinux context defined and then sshd won't start.

But in the default chroot environment (offered by online.net), selinux is disabled : that means that I cannot change any policy, I fall on the 'cannot downgrade file' error. So I need to chroot from scratch.

So how could I chroot with selinux enabled (which is in the original env) in fedora 25 server (rescued OS/selinux enabled) with ubuntu 18 (rescue OS/selinux disabled), so I could change sshd_config selinux policy ?

Comment: does running a recursive `restorecon` in the chroot with selinux in permissive mode set the right labels on files? What is the selinux/sshd failure in the audit.log?

Comment: no it didnt :( the ls -Z return a ? in place of the context so the audit.log offers to audit2allow.. which I cannot becaus of the disabled selinux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also `touch /.autorelabel` on the root partition of the system you want to boot. This will trigger a `restorecon` on the whole system at the next boot, and should fix the issue. The process will reboot the machine once the relabeling is done. Be aware that, depending on the disk and amount of files, this process can take quite long.

Another option would be to use extended attributes `xattr` to set the selinux contexts. This is actually where selinux file related information is stored and can be modified with `getfattr` and `setfattr` using `-m security.selinux`.

A third way to fixing your issue can be to switch selinux into permissive mode using kernel boot options by adding the option `enforcing=0`.

Comment: anyone know if you can plan9/nfs boot a chroot filesystem location in its own kernel for this autorelabel?

Comment: I gonna try : 3, 2 and 1 and see, thanks

Comment: @hargut /.autorelabel did the job : attr wasn't installed and I couldn't find the boot partition.

Comment: Great to hear that you could fix it! :)